# Java scripting in Katalon-Studio

Tags: java, katalon-studio

I have several java tests that I wrote and used to run them with Eclipse.

I want to import them to katalon and run them.

For example, I have a login script here:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class Login {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        IOException ioe = new IOException();
        //Initializing server
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();
        wd.manage().window().maximize();
        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //login
        System.out.println("*** login ***");
        wd.get("<URL>");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[1]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).click();
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[1]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).clear();
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[1]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("<USERNAME>");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[2]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).click();
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[2]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).clear();
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[2]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("<PASSWORD>");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']//paper-button[.='login']")).click();
        try { Thread.sleep(3000l); } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        if(wd.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText().contains("please login")){
            System.out.println("Login failed");
            throw ioe;
        }//End of login

        System.out.println("Login was executed successfully!");
        System.out.println("Testcase finished successfully!");
        wd.quit();
    }
}
```

I want to run it as is in katalon but I'm not sure how.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not sure how to run the main method, or add Selenium to the classpath so it can run?

Comment: I already added the necessary jars so it will recognize the classes and methods..I just don't know how to run it using katalon. Where do I need to paste my script?..Which modifications in my script do I need to do so it will run?

Comment: The documentation says there's a Run button. https://docs.katalon.com/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=786618#content/view/786618 and talks about the Script view https://docs.katalon.com/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=3179107#content/view/3179107

Comment: Yeah I tried using the script mode but it doesn't work..My script includes commands that invoke the chrome driver and which not needed in katalon groovey scripts so I don't know which modifications should I make in order for it to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try adding the existing java script without declaring class and main method and it work. 
In your example, please remove: **import org.openqa.selenium.*;** , replace it with:  **import org.openqa.selenium.By** then paste the remain script **without**

```
public class Login {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
}}
```

So your custom test case in Katalon would be:

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

        IOException ioe = new IOException();
        //Initializing server
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();
        wd.manage().window().maximize();
        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //login
        System.out.println("*** login ***");
        wd.get("<URL>");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[1]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).click();
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[1]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).clear();
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[1]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("<USERNAME>");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[2]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).click();
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[2]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).clear();
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']/div[2]/paper-input/paper-input-container/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("<PASSWORD>");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form']//paper-button[.='login']")).click();
        try { Thread.sleep(3000l); } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        if(wd.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText().contains("please login")){
            System.out.println("Login failed");
            throw ioe;
        }//End of login

        System.out.println("Login was executed successfully!");
        System.out.println("Testcase finished successfully!");
        wd.quit();
```